# Multiple authentication in podio php api

Tags: php, podio

I have created an app using the podio php api. The logged user will authenticate with his refresh token.

> Podio::authenticate('refresh_token', array('refresh_token' =>
>   USER_REFRESH_TOKEN ));

In some cases, I need to add the user details in to another app in podio. The logged user doesn't have the permission to access that app. This will cause a Podio Forbidden error.

Only the admin of the app have the right permission for this app.

How can we authenticate the user for inserting his details in the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The oauth tokens are stored in `Podio::$oauth` so you can switch that around whenever you want to authenticate as a different entity.

For example if you want to switch between two different apps:

```
// Authenticate as the first app
Podio::authenticate('app', ...);

// Here you can make API requests as the first app

// When you want to switch, store the current auth before doing your second auth
$first_app_auth = Podio::$oauth;

// Auth as the second app.
Podio::authenticate('app', ...);

// Now you can make API requests as the second app

// ...and switch back to the first app
$second_app_auth = Podio::$oauth;

// Auth as the first app again:
Podio::$oauth = $first_app_auth;

// Make API requests as the first app again
```

Comment: Hi Andreas, Shall we store the Podio::$oauth value to session.So this will avoid the app authentication for several times.

Comment: Can we use json_encode for storing the class instance in session?

Comment: Podio::$oauth is a PodioOAuth object and I wouldn't recommend trying to store that directly. See the Redis example here for how to extract the properties and properly instantiate a new PodioOAuth object upon retrieval: http://podio.github.io/podio-php/sessions/